# How do I calculate the work of a gas showed up on a graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have this graph of a gas:

[image: gas graph]

Now, I need to calculate work of it, based on ABCD cycle of changes (that's a bit confusing to me, do I calculate AB, BC, CD separately?). How do I do it?

Also, how can I calculate heat of this gas needed to exchange with enviroment, in order to maintain it's internal energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the definition of the work done by a gas?
http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1150/14Thermo/work.html